# SQL Server 2008 sa password expires automatically after some minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 was working fine last 2 months, but yesterday we taken Internet to system through second LAN port after that SQL Server 'sa' password is expiring automatically.

Sometimes I get this error

> No process is on other end of the pipe'  ERROR : 233

or sometimes

> login failed for user sa error 18456